# How to save a retina image, NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, png, retina-display

I am trying to create something that emulates that mac osx built in screen shot tool, where if you take a screenshot in a retina monitor (320x240), the image that results opens at the same size as it was taken, but it is retina in that the dpi is 144.

However, no matter what I do I can't seem to do the same thing.  I can save a image with the exact same metadata, specifications (as far as I can see), and it just opens up at double size.

Here is the data from the built in screenshot image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQBNo.png

Here is the data from the image I produce
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6jTg.png

The only difference I see is that the XMP exif data is different.
But for one, I can't seem to figure out how to change it, and 2, I don't see how that would make sense anyways so I think I'm still not seeing something that makes a retina image.

I theorize that there is some kind of a hidden flag that I'm missing that tells Preview to open up the builtin screenshot with 320x240 instead of it's pixel size, 640x480

And here is my code.  The NSImageEXIFData does not seem to be sticking

```
   NSBitmapImageRep *bmpImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                                    initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                    pixelsWide:640
                                    pixelsHigh:480
                                    bitsPerSample:8
                                    samplesPerPixel:4
                                    hasAlpha:YES
                                    isPlanar:NO
                                    colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                    bitmapFormat:NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
                                    bytesPerRow:0
                                    bitsPerPixel:0
                                    ];


   bmpImageRep.size=NSMakeSize(320,240);

   id profile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/Color LCD-FD6E9053-53B7-5224-5892-F9F7EC52CEF3.icc"];
   [bmpImageRep setProperty:NSImageColorSyncProfileData withValue:profile];

   NSDictionary *exif = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:640], kCGImagePropertyExifPixelXDimension, [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], kCGImagePropertyExifPixelYDimension, nil];
   [bmpImageRep setProperty:NSImageEXIFData withValue:exif];

   NSGraphicsContext *bitmapContext = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:bmpImageRep];
   [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
   [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext: bitmapContext];

   NSRect bgRect = NSMakeRect(0,0,320,240);
   [myImage drawInRect:bgRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

   [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];


   NSData* pngData= [bmpImageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType
                               properties:nil];
   return pngData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That screenshot information appears to be stored in the file-system's extended attributes rather than the specific format's image metadata. Those extended attributes will be duplicated along with a file copy or open/save (as long as the application does not explicitly change the attributes) but not with a content-only copy (e.i. create new file and replicate original file's content).

You can use the **xattr** command line tool to list the extended attributes of a file. Here is what you would expect for a screenshot:

com.apple.metadata:kMDItemIsScreenCapture
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureGlobalRect
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureType

And **sys/xattr.h** is the header that contains the functions necessary to manipulate the extended attributes of a file.

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, OSX records which images were captured using the screenshot tool, then tells Preview to open that image in half size. So it isn't actually possible to create an image that opens half size in Preview, unless you mess with the OS files somewhere. It doesn't really matter though because if you open an image taken with the screenshot tool in Chrome or another app besides Preview, it also opens at double size. So it seems to just be special casing Apple created for Preview+Built-in Screenshots.

This of course is all personal speculation because I couldn't actually find any documentation or more information on this-- I can tell you, however, that I created an exact replica of a built-in screenshot image. Including all of the metadata and properties associated with the image, and it still opened differently in Preview.

I tried changing any pertinent property in NSBitmapImageRef, CGImage, CGContext, to try to get this. Tried changing the NSEXIFProperties as well, to no avail. (Related, no matter what you change in the metadata it doesn't change the actual image-- turns out they're just labels. Which makes sense, because I've seen gifs with the .jpeg extension)

Here's an article of somebody who scales the image opened in preview back out, but that's the opposite of what I wanted to do

http://www.macissues.com/2014/03/29/adjust-retina-macbook-screenshots-to-be-actual-size/

Anyways, after much digging, I'm afraid I'm going to have to mark this case closed, for now. If anybody stumbles across this and finds a solution, please message me :)

Comment: I found that it is possible to take a screenshot, open it in photoshop, edit resize, etc and it will still open at half the size in preview when saved. One guess is that they are using a special color profile. When pasting stuff into the image, photoshop warns me that the color profile will change, but both profiles have exactly the same name.

Comment: @rasmus Yeah I noticed that too.  All of the metadata, every single bit, was all the same.  but it still opens at half size in preview-- but preview only.  So I gave up on it :\